# Getting names of objects that have and haven't some properties in their arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So I have an array of objects with another arrays in them and I want to get a new array of objects that have specific things in their arrays and exclude those who haven't. (It's in Javascript)

To be more specific. I have an array like this:

```
let chars = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    abilities: ['swim', 'jump', 'sing']
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    abilities: ['run', 'jump']
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    abilities: ['swim', 'run', 'sing']
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    abilities: ['jump', 'swim', 'run']
  }
];
```

And for example I want to get only those chars that can swim and jump but can't run.

I thought about making two arrays like

```
let includeAbilities = ['swim', 'jump'];
let excludeAbilities = ['run'];
```

and then compare them somehow but I don't really know how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: [Array some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Thank you for choosing my answer, I actually simplified it a little to use `every()` instead of `reduce()`. Please take a look.

Comment: @RoboRobok Thank you, it's much easier and more understandable for me now

Comment: You're welcome. You can upvote too if you'd like :)

Comment: To people who voted to close - how is this question "too broad"? SO trippin' as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a nice mix of `Array.prototype.filter` and `Array.prototype.every`:

```js
const filteredChars = chars.filter(character => (
    includeAbilities.every(
        ability => character.abilities.includes(ability)
    ) &&
    excludeAbilities.every(
        ability => !character.abilities.includes(ability)
    )
));
```

Result:

```js
[
    {
        name: 'John',
        abilities: ['swim', 'jump', 'sing']
    }
]
```

The only matching character in your case is John, because he can swim and jump, but he can't run.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let chars = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    abilities: ['swim', 'jump', 'sing']
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark',
    abilities: ['run', 'jump']
  },
  {
    name: 'Bob',
    abilities: ['swim', 'run', 'sing']
  },
  {
    name: 'Jack',
    abilities: ['jump', 'swim', 'run']
  }
];
// This is ES6 syntax, arrow functions: char => char.abilities.includes('swim') is the same as  
// function(char) { return char.abilities.includes('swim') };
const canSwim = chars.filter(char => char.abilities.includes('swim'));
console.log(canSwim);
// You can make it even shorter with destructuring objects
const canSwimAndSing = chars.filter(({
  abilities
}) => {
  return abilities.includes('swim') && abilities.includes('sing')
});
console.log(canSwimAndSing);
```